# Ajax update panel too slow in Asp.net. How to resolve?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I just update the ID passed in NavigateURL of Hyperlink during the selectedindexchanged in my RadioButtonList.

In Mozilla it takes 3.26 seconds for the ID to get updated in Hyperlink
The other browsers also takes too long.

How can i resolve this ?

I read a lot of articles and took the following measures :

Set Debug to false in web.config

Use conditional in Update mode

Only use the controls that has to be updated in the Update panel.

But still, it takes 3.26 seconds...

```
Protected Sub chlTypes_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chlTypes.SelectedIndexChanged
    If (chlTypes.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() <> "") And (chlTypes.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() <> "0") Then
        HypView.NavigateUrl = "~/Content.aspx?ID=" + chlTypes.SelectedItem.Value.ToString()
    End If 
End Sub

 <table id="tbl1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP1" runat="server"  UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="chlTypes" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP2"  runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <div class="caregiver_view_button">
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HypView" class="caregiver_view_button"   
                                     runat="server"><img src="/view_button.png" /></asp:HyperLink>

                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chlTypes" />
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: How complicated/big is the rest of the page? can you post the code for selectedindex_changed? w/o this info it's impossible to help.

Comment: @Icarus One thing to note, this is a user control and i use this control in home page of my website. There are 9 more user controls which i use in home page. But anyway the update panel updates only the control which resides inside it. correct ?

Comment: yes, only the control inside the updatepanel is updated but the whole page life cycle is executed. The code in all the other controls is also executed it's just that the only portion that's updated in the page is the update panel. You can debug this yourself.